# Evaluation of BlankNullSequence inside StringReplace

Tags: pattern-matching, string-manipulation

I would like to replace the occurrence of `"a(x)"` and `"b(x)"` in a list with `"a(x-na)"` and `"b(x-nb)"` where `na` and `nb` are the number of `a`'s and `b`'s respectively. `x-na` should be evaluated.
I've tried

```
list = {"a(1)", "a(2)", "a(3)", "b(4)", "b(5)", "b(6)"}
na = Total[StringCount[list, "a"]]
nb = Total[StringCount[list, "b"]]
StringReplace[list, {"a(" ~~ n___ ~~ ")" -> 
   "a(" <> ToString[n - na] <> ")"}]
```

> ```
> {"a(-3 + n)", "a(-3 + n)", "a(-3 + n)", "b(4)", "b(5)", "b(6)"}
> ```

But as you can see it is not working as intended.

Can you help me please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
StringReplace[
 list,
 {h_ ~~ "(" ~~ n_ ~~ ")" :> 
   h <> "(" <> ToString[ToExpression[n] - Symbol["n" <> h]] <> ")"
}]
```

> ```
>  {"a(-2)", "a(-1)", "a(0)", "b(1)", "b(2)", "b(3)"}
> ```

Tell me if anything is not clear.

And some fun:

```
Composition[
  Map[ToString@ToString[#, TraditionalForm] &],
  # /. h_[n_Integer] :> h[n - CountsBy[#, Head][h]] &,
  Map[ToExpression[#, TraditionalForm] &]

  ]@{"a(1)", "a(2)", "a(3)", "b(4)", "b(5)", "b(6)"}
```

> ```
> {"a(-2)", "a(-1)", "a(0)", "b(1)", "b(2)", "b(3)"}
> ```

Comment: That is good. You did more than I requested since I can do two StringReplace for a and b separately. Thanks!